# Executing SSIS package using command prompt

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dtexec

I am trying to execute an SSIS package using command prompt.

I have visual studio 2019 community edition installed and have selected 'Data storage and processing' during the installation.
Also installed SQL server integration services projects from visual studio extensions.

I looked for Dtexec.exe and found it at the below mentioned locations.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn

I couldn't find a 64bit Dtexec.exe under C:\Program Files

I have created an SSIS package using visual studio 2019.

I tried executing the package from command line using a batch file.

*"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /FILE "C:\Users\Ash\source\repos\DR Activity 1\DR Activity 1\Package.dtsx" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EWCDI
pause*

I get an error message stating

*There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.Exception: The Script Task "ST_07a17c9047774ce7ad850af7a94a9ca5" uses version 15.0 script that is not supported in this release of Integration Services*

Comment: `Microsoft SQL Server\120`, that `120` means you're running SQL Server 2014, however, the package appears to be in SQL server 2019 version. You need to set to project's Target Server Version to 2014. This may mean you'll need to rewrite your script tasks, due to them using a newer version of Net Framework.

Comment: I'll change the project's Target server version to 2014 and check if it works. Thanks.